# Playback of Audio file on key press is delayed

Tags: c#, naudio

I made a small program that plays back sounds when you press keys.

It uses a [global keyboard hook](https://gist.github.com/Ciantic/471698) to capture key presses and play back `wav` files using [NAudio](https://github.com/naudio/NAudio).

However playback lags on some computers and plays a few seconds after the key has been pressed. Could this be an HDD/SSD or CPU speed issue or is it a programming issue? What can be done to solve it?

Tried on 4 computers, 2 lagged, 2 did not.

- My `SSD`/`i7` - did not lag.
- My `HDD`/`Core2Duo` - did not lag.
- Friend's `SSD`/`i7` -  lagged.
- Friend's `HDD`/`i7` -  lagged.

---

#### Program

Info
https://github.com/MattMcManis/Ink

Source
https://github.com/MattMcManis/Ink/tree/master/source/Ink

Download
https://github.com/MattMcManis/Ink/releases

---

#### App.xaml.cs

Start the Keyboard Listener.

```
// Application Startup
//
private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
    th = new Thread(() => RunKeyListener());
    th.IsBackground = true;
    th.Start();
    th.Join();
}

// Keyboard Listener
//
private void RunKeyListener()
{
    KListener.KeyDown += new RawKeyEventHandler(KListener_KeyDown);
}

// Key Down
//
void KListener_KeyDown(object sender, RawKeyEventArgs args)
{
    Sound.KeyPressed(args);
}
```

---

#### MainWindow.xaml.cs

KeyboardListener Class is in here.

https://gist.github.com/Ciantic/471698

---

#### Sound.cs

```
private static string wavKeyChar = "Sounds\\character.wav";
private static string wavKeyNum = "Sounds\\number.wav";

public static WaveFileReader wav = null;
public static WaveOutEvent output = null;

// Key Pressed
//
public static void KeyPressed(RawKeyEventArgs args)
{
    // Letters
    if (args.Key >= Key.A && args.Key <= Key.Z)
    {
        PlaySound(wavKeyChar);
    }

    // Numbers
    else if (args.Key >= Key.D0 && args.Key <= Key.D9)
    {
        PlaySound(wavKeyNum);
    }
}

// Play Sound
//
public static void PlaySound(string sound)
{
    wav = new WaveFileReader(sound);

    output = new WaveOutEvent();
    output.NumberOfBuffers = 3;
    output.DesiredLatency = 500;
    output.Init(wav);
    output.Play();
}
```

Comment: First question to ask is how big are the files?  Your using .WAV, if you convert to mp3 they are smaller and will load faster.  That could be the issue if the files are large and over network may take a bit to get them loaded.

Comment: @Brad I was using mp3 at first, but I think I read somewhere that it saves metadata to the mp3 each time it opens/closes it and takes longer to load, but that may have been with `MediaPlayer` instead of `NAudio`. I will try again.

Comment: That may be the case, but if they are large files, I think the loading time would be sped up better using .mp3 then any time any updates would be made.

Answer (score 0):

Try to show a MessageBox or something, to understand if the delayed event is the sound itself or the keypress event.
If the MessageBox shows before the sound is played then it's not a problem of keyboard hook library.

Comment: I will set this up and try to find if this is the case.